# Inserting NOT A HTML code into CLASSIC Google Sites

Tags: google-classic-sites, javascript, html

Recently, I was developing a classic Google Sites, but wanted to add a RevolverMaps Widget. The widget I was using was RevolverMaps Standard GL (you can search for revolver maps on google and click on the "get a widget" tab and the first one is what i wanted). However, when I paste the code into the HTML box in the classic google sites it says error or something I forgotten but it just didnt work. Can someone help me with this? In the box is the code I have: `<script type="text/javascript" src="//rf.revolvermaps.com/0/0/6.js?i=5zpda5iu2nz&amp;m=1c&amp;c=9d8b63&amp;cr1=ff00ff&amp;f=comic_sans_ms&amp;l=0&amp;v0=100&amp;z=11&amp;rx=0&amp;hi=100&amp;hc=ffc000&amp;rs=100&amp;as=100&amp;cr0=ff00ff&amp;cw=00fff6&amp;cb=baff00" async="async"></script>`

*Notes*:

1. I am using CLASSIC Google Sites not new google sites
2. I am not a tech expert I am just a graduating student at a primary school in Singapore (a.k.a. Primary 6 if you are a Singaporean you should know it) and I have LITERALLY no idea what codes or HTML whatever that means
3. Hence, try to explain and avoid using too complex terms I cant understand as much as possible or you can send a video link if you know one I can watch. However, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript in Google Sites](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/javascript-in-google-sites)

Comment: Ok but then I seriously have no clue how I can build a google gadget. I am just a 12 years old wanting to add this cool 3d globe thingy. Maybe you can show me how I can do it like literally just show me no need to explain I have 0% experience in coding or programming But thanks anyway I appreciate your help!!

Comment: Ok I really dont know how to create a gadget I am just a 12 years old so I have 0% expertise in coding or programming whatever and also the codewrapper thingy in the google sites I searched and there is no such gadget

Comment: This site has a minimal age. AFAIK for US residents is 13, if you are in another country, you should change your profile.

Comment: If you are motivated you can learn, but you might should start by learning how to create a simple web application by using Google Apps Script (it was mentioned in several answers to the same previously referred question)